# How disable user login via remember token?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, cookies

Laravel allows authenticating users with a `remember_token` stored in cookie.

In my `user` table I have an `active` column which is a `boolean (1, 0)`.

If for example a user is fired, you need to disable his ability to login; so you change the `active` value to 0.

But what you are going to do with his cookies?

**NOTICE!** I've written this in a very primitive way! The question is how properly handle such situations.

Comment: You can delete session for inactive user or add a conditional to login system where session checks.

Answer (score 1):

As you have no way to remove remember cookie, you need to implement a check in your application that would make sure that all users that log in have active status.

One way you could do this is to implement a listener for **auth.login** event and check the status there.

```
class CheckUserStatusHandler {
  public function handle($user) {
    if (!$user->active) Auth::logout($user);
  }
}
```

Logout method will logout user **and** remove remember token.

Then register the listener in your **EventServiceProvider**:

```
protected $listen = [
  'auth.login' => [
        CheckUserStatusHandler::class
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be able to overwrite AuthenticatesUsers::getCredentials() in AuthController and add the status to prevent them from logging in regardless of the cookie?

```
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request, and force the
 * user to be activated in order to be authenticated with the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');

    return array_merge($credentials, [
        'status' => 1,
    ]);
}
```